# How exactly do I set the protected branches regex format to limit what can be pushed to the repo?

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to figure out the regex pattern usage in GitLab in order to

1. Prevent any branch that does not follow the naming convention from be pushed up
2. Specify for example only these name formats can be used and at least 1 must be used: ^(bug)?(release)?(feature)?/.*\n

Has anyone done this with GitLab and can assist?

Tried the ***'Settings > Repository > Protected branches > Protect a branch wildcard'*** to try and do this but it does not appear to work. I get 0 matches

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a regex to only verify if the branch name starts with bug or release or feature? if so, this does the trick `^(bug|release|feature).*`

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that. I was using the 'Settings > Repository > Protected branches > Protect a branch wildcard' to try and do this but it does not appear to work. I get 0 matches but I have many branches that do contain those leading keywords.

Comment: Create a new push rule, those support regex https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected branch rule patterns do not support regex. Wildcard (`*`) is the only supported metacharacter. If you want a similar effect to you have in your regex `^(bug|release|feature).*`, you will need to make multiple protected branch rules.

For example, you could make three rules:

- `bug*`
- `feature*`
- `release*`

Comment: How then would I block someone from creating a branch that does not contain one of the above 3 rules?

Comment: Use a plain wildcard rule, `*`, and set `No One` for push/merges. That will match all branches. It can be used in combination with the other rules without conflict ([most permissive rule wins](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#configure-multiple-protected-branches-by-using-a-wildcard)) @edjm

Comment: Thank you very much. I had branch stuff done in the past but I could have sworn it was with regex patterns. Your post definitely helped me out.